# How to set icons for buttons of qxl.dialog in your project?

Tags: qooxdoo

I installed `qxl.dialog` package, created a dialog but there no images for buttons. In description of the package said: in your theme directory of your project you have to extend an icon class and define paths for specific alias such as `qxl.dialog.icon.(ok|cancel|info|warning|error)`. But I don't use specific icon theme and change theme at runtime. I mean I don't depend on one theme. I would like to get icon theme of current theme and add programmatically alias for this icon theme. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a alias manager which allows to define alias and their values. It can be used for defining `qxl.dialog.icon.(ok|cancel|info|warning|error)`.

```
const title = qx.theme.manager.Icon.getInstance().getTheme().title
const manager = qx.util.AliasManager.getInstance()
manager.add("qxl.dialog.icon.ok", `qx/icon/${title}/22/actions/dialog-ok.png`);
```